# ext.js Window doesn't adjust to buttons size

Tags: extjs

When I set a long string in the button, window does not adjust to buttons size. I have made a buttonWidth variable, to make window size bigger than buttons size, but it does not work. Also dbWindow width : auto does not do a job. Of course I could set greater width value, but I want to make this window dynamic and "button text length proof".

```
showDbWindow : function(){
        var me = this;
        this.dbWindow = new Ext4.Window({
                width   : 610,
                title   : me.windowName,
                items: [{
                margin: '10 10 10 10',
                    xtype: 'component',
                    html: me.question
                },
                {
                    buttons : [{
                    itemId : 'aktualizuj',
                                text    : "d,smndfnrifnoaeirnfiainre,mvva,revaervnlerknv",
                                handler : me.executeQuery,
                                scope : me
                            },
                            {
                            itemId: 'dalej',
                                text    : "d,smndfnrifnoaeirnfiainre,mvva,revaervnlerknv",
                                handler : me.confirm,
                                scope : me
                            },
                            {
                            itemId: 'powrot',
                                text    : "d,smndfnrifnoaeirnfiainre,mvva,revaervnlerknv",
                                handler : me.closeWindow,
                                scope : me
                            }
                        ]
                }]

        });
        this.dbWindow.show();
        var buttonWidth = this.dbWindow.getChildItemsToDisable('')[0].getWidth() + this.dbWindow.getChildItemsToDisable('')[1].getWidth() + this.dbWindow.getChildItemsToDisable('')[2].getWidth();
        this.dbWindow.setWidth(buttonWidth);
        debugger;
    },
```

[window with buttons pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vbn4.png)

As you can see, first button is partly **hidden** . What is important is the fact, that button is not cutted. After widening the window by mouse coursor, the buttons are all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add some extra width (padding between buttons) and next use `doLayout` on window.

```
showDbWindow: function() {
  var me = this;
  this.dbWindow = new Ext4.Window({
    width: 610,
    title: me.windowName,
    items: [{
        margin: '10 10 10 10',
        xtype: 'component',
        html: me.question
      },
      {
        buttons: [{
            itemId: 'aktualizuj',
            text: "d,smndfnrifnoaeirnfiainre,mvva,revaervnlerknv",
            handler: me.executeQuery,
            scope: me
          },
          {
            itemId: 'dalej',
            text: "d,smndfnrifnoaeirnfiainre,mvva,revaervnlerknv",
            handler: me.confirm,
            scope: me
          },
          {
            itemId: 'powrot',
            text: "d,smndfnrifnoaeirnfiainre,mvva,revaervnlerknv",
            handler: me.closeWindow,
            scope: me
          }
        ]
      }
    ]

  });
  this.dbWindow.show();
  var buttonWidth = this.dbWindow.getChildItemsToDisable('')[0].getWidth() + this.dbWindow.getChildItemsToDisable('')[1].getWidth() + this.dbWindow.getChildItemsToDisable('')[2].getWidth() + 40;
  this.dbWindow.setWidth(buttonWidth);
  this.dbWindow.doLayout();
  debugger;
},
```

I suggest using `toolbar` with `enableOverflow` instead.